# go command accessing self-signed certificate

Tags: go, certificate, self-signed, goland

I am using Go with self-hosted Git (gitea) with self-signed certificate.
However with self-signed certificate most Go commands don't work correctly including "go mod". I have to do "go get -insecure ...." before I do any other `go mod` commands. I can't even do "go list" because it doesn't seem to accept the `-insecure` flag. And most IDE tool won't work correctly, especially GoLand.

What is the best way to go about this kind of issue? Do I have to get the certificate and add to trusted certificate locally? Or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Either make your own CA and use it to sign the remote and then add the public part to the client that is running go or use a CA provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vorsprung said, I as our MIS to provide the self-signed CA and installed and trust it on my local computer.